# Java - Pasar método como valor en HashMap

Tags: java, poo

Estoy buscando una forma de procesar la acción tomada por un jugador en una aventura de texto. Anteriormente lo implementé en Python utilizando un diccionario, pero en el caso de Java no se como pasar un método sin los paréntesis para invocarlo.

Player class (Leer el método llamado processAction):

```
private String name;
private char gender;
private Map<String, List<Item>> inventory = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Character, Integer> position = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Player() {
    this("Gah", 'o');
}

public Player(String name, char gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.inventory.put("albums", new ArrayList<Item>());
    this.inventory.put("instruments", new ArrayList<Item>());
    this.position.put('n', 0);
    this.position.put('e', 0);
    this.position.put('s', 0);
    this.position.put('w', 0);
}

public String getPositionToString() {

    String positionStr = "";

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> coordinate : this.position.entrySet()) {
        positionStr += coordinate.getValue() + " ";
    }

    return positionStr.trim();

}

public Room getCurrentRoom() {

    Room currentRoom = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Room> room : GameMap.getGameMap().getRooms().entrySet()) {
        if (room.getKey().equals(this.getPositionToString()))
            currentRoom = room.getValue();
    }

    return currentRoom;

}

public Plot getCurrentStory() {
    return this.getCurrentRoom().getStory();
}

public List<String> getCurrentStoryValues() {

    Map<String, String> currentRoomStory = this.getCurrentStory().getText();
    List<String> storyValues = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> storyPair : currentRoomStory.entrySet()) {
        storyValues.add(storyPair.getValue());
    }

    return storyValues;

}

public void updateNorth(char direction) {
    if (position.get('s') > 0) {
        position.put('s', position.get('s') - 1);
    }
    else {
        position.put('n', position.get('n') + 1);
    }

}

public void updateSouth(char direction) {
    if (position.get('n') > 0) {
        position.put('n', position.get('n') - 1);
    }
    else {
        position.put('s', position.get('s') + 1);
    }
}

public void updateEast(char direction) {
    if (position.get('w') > 0) {
        position.put('w', position.get('w') - 1);
    }
    else {
        position.put('e', position.get('e') + 1);
    }
}

public void updateWest(char direction) {
    if (position.get('e') > 0) {
        position.put('e', position.get('e') - 1);
    }
    else {
        position.put('w', position.get('w') + 1);
    }
}

public void move(char direction) {
    switch(direction) {
        case 'n':
            updateNorth(direction);
            break;
        case 'e':
            updateEast(direction);
            break;
        case 's':
            updateSouth(direction);
            break;
        case 'w':
            updateWest(direction);
            break;
    }
}

public void take(String itemName) {

    Room currentRoom = this.getCurrentRoom();
    List<Item> currentRoomItems = currentRoom.getItems();
    boolean itemTaken = false;

    for (Item currentItem : currentRoomItems) {
        if (itemName.equals(currentItem.getName())) {
            this.inventory.get(currentItem.getGroup()).add(currentItem);
            itemTaken = true;
        }

        if (itemTaken) {
            this.getCurrentStory().updateStory(currentItem.getName());
            currentRoomItems.remove(currentItem);
            System.out.println("You got " + currentItem.getName() + '!');
            break;
        }
    }

}

public String explore() {

    String formattedStory = "";

    for (String text : this.getCurrentStoryValues()) {
        formattedStory += text + "\n";
    }

    return formattedStory;

}

public void processAction(String actionDecision, Object... args) {

    List<String> actions = this.getCurrentRoom().getActions();
    Map<String, Void> actionInvocation = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    actionInvocation.put("explore", this.explore); // Aquí
    actionInvocation.put("move", this.move); // Aquí
    actionInvocation.put("take", this.move); // Aquí

//        for (String action : actions) {
//            if (actionDecision.equals(action))
//                this.
//        }

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public Map<String, List<Item>> getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}

public Map<Character, Integer> getPosition() {
    return position;
}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es que si la opción elegida por el jugador es válida, entonces pueda referenciar la acción haciendo actionInvocation.getKey(action)(), ¿Es eso posible, o debo invocar la función inmediatamente dentro del HashMap? En el caso de la última, no lo hago porque los métodos move y take requieren argumentos.

Comment: Nunca había visto usar un HashMap <String, Void> y me parece interesante pero, ¿podrías explicar por qué pretendes implementarlo así? Intuyo que la lista `actions` te da las posibles acciones realizables por el jugador dentro de esa `Room`, ¿por qué no comparar simplemente si `actionDecision` lo contiene dicha lista?

Comment: Hola Manu, a ver si lo he entendido bien... Tú quieres que al hacer `actionInvocation.getKey(action)`, suponiendo que `action = "move"` se llame al método `move()` directamente, no?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es pasar objetos que implementen una interfaz común

Comment: de donde a donde quieres mover qué?

Comment: Exactamente como lo ha señalado David.
He encontrado una forma "mejor" al hacer un switch statement, pero aún tendría problemas con los argumentos de las acciones.
Tal vez pasando vargs, podría funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

A partir de Java 8, puedes agregar al mapa las referencias a los metodos que quieres invocar como `this::move`, pero necesitaras que todos los metodos tengan la misma firma.

Asumiendo que eventualmente necesitaras pasar distintos argumentos para esos metodos, podrias utilizar la interfaz funcional `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` con un arreglo de objetos como parametro:

```
Map<String, Consumer<Object[]>> actionInvocation = new LinkedHashMap<>();
actionInvocation.put("explore", this::explore); // Aquí
actionInvocation.put("move", this::move); // Aquí
actionInvocation.put("take", this::take); // Aquí
```

Pero eso requiere que todos esos metodos referenciados cumplan con la interfaz de `java.util.function.Consumer<T>`:

```
void accept(T t);
```

Por lo que para la parametrizacion `Object[]` tendrias modificar la firma de `move`, `explore` y `take` a algo como:

```
public void move(Object... parametros) {
    char direction = (char) parametros[0];
    switch(direction) {
        case 'n':
            updateNorth(direction);
            break;
        case 'e':
            updateEast(direction);
            break;
        case 's':
            updateSouth(direction);
            break;
        case 'w':
            updateWest(direction);
            break;
    }
}
```

Y para invocarlo tendrias que pasarle un arreglo de objetos:

```
char direction = 'w';
actionInvocation.getKey("move")(new Object[]{direction});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Justo pensé en pasar vargs a las funciones move y take, de manera que las pueda invocar sin parámetros y luego dentro la función pida un objeto, o una dirección, de acuerdo a la función.
Pero lo primero, con respecto a la interfaz funcional consumer, no estoy seguro de entender, pero buscaré información para entenderlo.

Comment: Una interfaz funcional es una interfaz comun y corriente, solo que tiene un solo método